# Type specificity for arguments in Julia

Tags: julia

In the following scenario, which is the better way of declaring the function

```
addnum(x::Float,y::Float) = x + y
```

vs

```
addnum(x::Float64,y::Float64) = x + y
```

The Julia manual [style guide](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/style-guide/index.html) urges to avoid writing overly-specific types. When is the former preferred and when the latter?

Comment: by `Float` you mean `AbstractFloat`? as the mantra goes: "strictly type your types, loosely type your functions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using type specification to override a different version of the function, it is often better to simply drop the type annotation:

addnum(x, y) = x + y

since this allows the function to work for integer and complex types, too, and the compile can then specialize the function automatically at compile time.

Comment: In a case when the arguments can only take float values, which definition would be better Float vs. Float32 vs. Float64? And what determines which type definition to use?

Comment: Because the compiler is likely to keep type stability best with Float64, I would use Float64, since that is what all versions of Julia calculate floating point in, unless there was reason to think you will be having to use a different kind of floating point (for example, some image array element types are smaller floating point types).  But I'd be surprised if it made a difference.

Comment: I would definitely say drop the type annotations anyway. Only use the annotations if you need to catch it as an error if it's not a float. If you use `Float64` it will _fail_ if it gets `Float32`, so `AbstractFloat` is better. (`Float` doesn't exist.)

Comment: It will also fail on integers, rationals, bigfloats, complex, etc. etc.